# Behavior of Python subprocess on django+nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, subprocess, python-venv

I have a simple code like:

```
subprocess.run(
    ["python3",
     "action.py",
     "--options"]
)
```

In action.py I import some packages, perform a small script

It works properly when I launch it on the built-in Django-server, but when I add Nginx-server as a wrapper, I get

```
 "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulename'".
```

Why this error might occur exactly with Nginx and how I can correct it?

Launch with shell=True or venv="path/to/venv" don`t work for me

Comment: I’m guessing the “python3” that resolves to is not your venv’s python and its pythonpath is not the same as the Djangos python. That django’s python is in sys.argv[0] iirc, maybe try passing that?